# What are TestKit, TestActorRef and TestProbe in Akka?

Tags: unit-testing, akka

kind of new to akka actors

but will like the know the use and differences between the TestKit , TastActorRef and TestProbe

as used in akka unit testing.

I have seen them used for unit testing akka systems but do not seem to understand the concept

tried searching the internet but looks like documentation is sparse.

Any brief explanation is welcomed.

thanks ll .

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your searching skills need some honing, I think:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/testing.html

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/java/testing.html

But in short:

- TestKit can be used as base-class for your tests, it provides an internal actor which can receive replies and a host of assertion methods for these replies
- TestProbe is a wrapped-up TestKit which you can inject into message flows

These two were about integration testing, the next is for unit testing:

- TestActorRef allows you to peek inside the actor and run its code synchronously, JUnit style.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following two links very helpful (along with the official Akka docs) when I was getting to grips with testing Akka in Java:

- http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2012/03/testing-akka-actors-from-java.html
- https://github.com/write2munish/Akka-Essentials/tree/master/AkkaUnitTest